# Ember.js this in callback

Tags: ember.js, callback, this, promise

I have an action in my controller to create a new `page` which is one of my models.

Afterwards, I want to clear out the form and transition to the new `page`.

Here is my code:

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.ObjectController.extend

    newSlug: (->
        # some function
    ).property('newTitle')

    newMenuName: # some property

    actions:
        addNewPage: ->
            # Get the site
            site = @get('model')
            # Get all the pages associated with the site
            pages = site.get('pages')

            # ...
            # snipped a bunch out to save space
            # ...

            # Create a new page passing in our title, slug and menu_name
            page = pages.createRecord({title: title, slug: slug, menu_name: menu_name, menu_1: menu_1, menu_2: menu_2, menu_1_order: menu_1_order, menu_2_order: menu_2_order})
            page.save().then(onSuccess, onError)

            onSuccess = (page) ->

                page = this.store.find('page', slug)
                console.log('Slug: ' + slug + ' ' + page.slug)

                @set('newTitle', '')
                @set('newSlug', '')
                @set('newMenuName', '')
                $('#addPageModal').foundation('reveal', 'close')
                @transitionToRoute('page', page)
```

But I'm getting the error that `this` has no method `set`. I have even tried using `self = this` but it gives me the same error.

Any thoughts?

BTW, in case you're wondering, inside `onSuccess`, `page` is not defined, so I have to look it up again. I thought a promise was supposed to return the data sent back from the API.

EDIT:

I must look like a total imbecile, but once again, right after posting a question here, I find (part) of the answer myself. Turns out in CoffeeScript (so far I'm not a big fan of it in combination with Ember.js) I needed the `=>` so my callback function becomes:

```
onSuccess = (page) =>

    page = this.store.find('page', slug)
    console.log('Slug: ' + slug + ' ' + page.slug)

    @set('newTitle', '')
    @set('newSlug', '')
    @set('newMenuName', '')
    $('#addPageModal').foundation('reveal', 'close')
    @transitionToRoute('page', page)
```

However, `page` is still not defined. Not sure what to do about that.

EDIT:
And the correct answer is....

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.ObjectController.extend

newSlug: (->
    # some function
).property('newTitle')

newMenuName: # some property

actions:
    addNewPage: ->
        # Get the site
        site = @get('model')
        # Get all the pages associated with the site
        pages = site.get('pages')

        # ...
        # snipped a bunch out to save space
        # ...

        onSuccess = (page) ->

            @set('newTitle', '')
            @set('newSlug', '')
            @set('newMenuName', '')
            $('#addPageModal').foundation('reveal', 'close')
            @transitionToRoute('page', page.get('slug'))

        # And just for completeness
        onError = (page) =>
        # Do something

        # Create a new page passing in our title, slug, menu_name, etc.
        page = pages.createRecord({title: title, slug: slug, menu_name: menu_name, menu_1: menu_1, menu_2: menu_2, menu_1_order: menu_1_order, menu_2_order: menu_2_order})
        page.save().then(onSuccess, onError)
```

Comment: Doing => in CoffeeScript or ES6 is pretty similar to self=this in your context

Comment: Is there any reason you're refinding page in `onSuccess`?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum well, that's what I thought and I tried it, but it didn't work. Would I have defined that inside the controller, inside the actions or inside the callback function?

Comment: @kingpin2k yes, because ```page``` didn't return anything from the promise. I was actually wondering if page.save() occurs before page.createRecord() so that in the promise ```page``` would still be undefined or null actually.

Comment: @reblevins try moving onSuccess and onFailure _above_ the `page.save()` call, they might be hoisted - thus undefined causing them to pass as `undefined` to the `.then` call which can cause it to ignore them.

Comment: but if you don't define page in the callback, `page` will be brought in via closure.  Additionally Ben is right, onSuccess should be getting hoisted, and that callback shouldn't be being called.

Comment: Ok, I feel dumb. I was calling ```console.log('Slug: ' + slug + ' ' + page.slug)``` and ```page.slug``` was undefined so I assumed ```page``` was undefined. However, that should have been ```page.get('slug')```. I guess I assumed that it would work the same in a controller as in a Handlebars template (or like it does in Ruby).  Thanks folks for your help. @BenjaminGruenbaum I'm still wondering though why self=this didn't work for me. Can you help me understand where I should have put that?

Comment: This is how JavaScript functions work. When instead of  `function foo(){` CoffeeScript compiles to `var foo = function(){` which has to come _above_ the `.then`. `alert(x);var x = function(){};` - alerts `undefined`. When a`.then` is passed undefined it ignores it.